# Для чего нужен Boolean в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Для чего нужен Boolean в JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная типа `Boolean` может содержать лишь одно из двух возможных значений: `Истина` либо `Ложь`
Основное использование `Boolean` - проверка условия на истинность.

```
if($a > $b) {/* code here */} //$a > $b возвращает Boolean
```

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос немного не об этом, как я понимаю человек спрашивает зачем в javascript существует **объект** Boolean (если быть точным конструктор). Ответ на этот вопрос довольно прост - в JavaScript, практически все является объектом. Object, String, Number, Array, Function etc. (за исключением null и undefined, хотя из undefined тоже можно сделать объект :DDD, но это не везде работает и это хак)
Boolean не исключение. Раз у boolean типа данных есть конструктор, соответственно у него, даже, есть и прототип. Хотя на него и наложены ограничения и реализация языка скрывает от нас то, что это объект (мы не можем добавлять свои свойства, естественно, так само как и читать) - это объект.

Ну и теперь немного javascript "магии".

```
Boolean.prototype.functionTest = function(){ return "как не странно работает"; }
Boolean.prototype.SOME_PROTO_VAR = 'и это тоже ;D';

// вызывать можно так
console.log( (true).functionTest() ); // -> как не странно работает
// или так
var bool = false;
console.log( bool.SOME_PROTO_VAR );  // -> и это тоже ;D
```

Если кратко подвести итого - это особенность реализации языка, если быть более точным - языков семейства ECMAScript.

Comment: Вот за **это** я иногда боюсь JavaScript!

Comment: Это не для джунов. Если вы начинающий - вы не обязаны этого знать. Я тоже боялся когда-то, теперь это мой любимый язык

Comment: меня обстоятесльства застивили взяться за js, начал читать книгу JavaScript Patterns, подкрепляя практикой работы с backbone.js и одним одностраничным приложением, и этот язык мне нравится всё больше и больше...своей выразительностью и лаконичностью, гибкостью...скоро он подвинет моего фаворита=)

Answer (score 0):

**Логический тип.** Да/нет/нету/не знаю такого.